# Django CSRF Issues

Tags: python, django, csrf

I'm attempting to make a simple login framework for use later on in my site, at the moment its very basic, but I keep being stalled by the Django CSRF protection

Steps I have taken:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```

Enabled the CSRFViewMiddleware

```
def request_page(request):
if(request.POST.get('btnLogin')):

    if(handleLogin( (request.POST.get('TFUsername')), (request.POST.get('TFPassword')))):
        return HttpResponse("yep")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("nope")
```

which calls this method in the login handler.py

```
def handleLogin(enteredUsername, enteredPassword):
EvalDBLogin.objects
b = EvalDBLogin(username = enteredUsername,password = enteredPassword)
if b.exists():
    return True
else:
    return False
```

The view function does pass a request to the template's render method as shown above

Every form element contains  {% csrf_token %}

```
 <td width="252">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="272"><table width="258" height="115" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td width="248" height="27"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="#">{% csrf_token %}
          <label for="TFUsername"></label>
          <input name="TFUsername" type="text" class="loginBoxes" id="TFUsername" value="username" size="100" maxlength="42" border="5" width="200px"/>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="26"><input name="TFPassword" type="password" class="loginBoxes" id="TFPassword" value="password" size="42" maxlength="42" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="43">



          <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" id="btnLogin" value="Submit" />
        </form></td>
      </tr>
      </table></td>
    <td width="252">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
```

Template Context Processors looks as follows:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"LoginSystem",
 )
```

Am I missing something, or is it a technical problem my end?

Issue shown : http://puu.sh/jsRQh/384a552b2e.png

I know there are a few questions already on SO regarding this, but I couldn't quite find one that fully answered my question.

As a side note, the same error is returned if i exempt the method below from csrf

Help is greatly appreciated!

rendered Html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .loginBoxes {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #AFAFAF;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
#TFUsername {
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    padding: 20px; 
    width:  300px;
    height: 20px; 
} 
#TFPassword {
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    padding: 20px; 
    width:  300px;
    height: 20px; 
} 
#btnLogin{
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #0066FF;
    display: table-cell;
    width:  310px;
    display:table-cell;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    height: 31px; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="800" height="722" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="800" height="253" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td width="252">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="272"><table width="258" height="115" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td width="248" height="27"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="#">
              <label for="TFUsername"></label>
              <input name="TFUsername" type="text" class="loginBoxes" id="TFUsername" value="username" size="100" maxlength="42" border="5" width="200px"/>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="26"><input name="TFPassword" type="password" class="loginBoxes" id="TFPassword" value="password" size="42" maxlength="42" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="43">



              <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" id="btnLogin" value="Submit" />
            </form></td>
          </tr>
          </table></td>
        <td width="252">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Rendering of Template

```
def index(request):
template = loader.get_template('loginSystem/index.html')

return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

Comment: You seem to have multiple forms on that page for some reason. You only need one form to submit the username and password, and only one `csrf_token` in that form.

Comment: Yep, sorry I should've added that to the question

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey Thanks, I've revised the code above

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? And why are you converting `TFUsername` and `TFPassword` to ints before passing them to `handleLogin`?

Comment: 403 error Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

Comment: @grantmcconnaughey Good point, should probably fix that... , legacy code

Comment: Your `handleLogin` suggests that you are storing passwords in plain text in your database. That's a really bad idea. Django comes with login views, it's much better to try and use them rather than try to cheat your own.

Comment: @Alasdair this is a temporary measure before the system uses the Single Sign On service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have included the csrf middleware twice. You can remove it the second time.

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

You can remove the `csrf_protect` decorator, since you are using the middleware, all views will be protected by default.

Since you are using `RequestContext`, you can remove `"django.core.context_processors.csrf"` from your template context processors, since it's always included.

The request context should be the third argument to `render_to_response`, not the second:

```
return render_to_response('loginSystem/index1.html', {}, csrfContext)
```

But you'd be better to use the `render` shortcut instead, then you don't need a request context at all.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

return render(request, 'loginSystem/index1.html')
```

If it still doesn't work after making those changes, please update your question above, and include what the post what the rendered template looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've made the corrections you suggested and have updated my question accordingly, there is now a link present to an image of the resulting screen, the same error persists

Comment: I've removed the reloading of the page and place in a simple HTTP Response to assist with debugging

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. You haven't shown what the rendered html is **before** you submit the form.

Comment: Rendered HTML is posted :)

Comment: Ok, the rendered html shows that the csrf token is missing. How are you rendering that template? The `request_page` view you have posted only seems to cover the post request.

Comment: Using HTTP Response, copied the tutorial

Comment: Changed it to the "official" way, now the page doesn't crash but doesn't load anything either, thanks for your help i'll keep at it

Comment: If use the render shortcut for the template that displays the login form, the csrf_token tag should work, i.e. return `render(request, 'loginSystem/index.html')`.